# How can I create new map with new values but same keys from an existing map?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have an existing map in Groovy.
I want to create a new map that has the same keys but different values in it.

Eg.:

```
def scores = ["vanilla":10, "chocolate":9, "papaya": 0]
//transformed into
def preference = ["vanilla":"love", "chocolate":"love", "papaya": "hate"]
```

Any way of doing it through some sort of closure like:

```
def preference = scores.collect {//something}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Where are you getting those values (love, love, hate) from?

Comment: Suppose it is range based `10..9 = love, 8..6 = like, 5..2= meh, 1..0 = hate`.
What I need to know is how to use a closure that is aware of key-value pairs and generates more key-value pairs for me, all into a new map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice, functional style solution(including your ranges, and easy to modify):

```
def scores = [vanilla:10, chocolate:9, papaya: 0]
// Store somewhere
def map = [(10..9):"love", (8..6):"like", (5..2):"meh", (1..0):"hate"]
def preference = scores.collectEntries { key, score -> [key, map.find { score in it.key    }.value] }
// Output: [vanilla:love, chocolate:love, papaya:hate]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collectEntries`

```
scores.collectEntries { k, v ->
    [ k, 'new value' ]
}
```

An alternative to using a `map` for the ranges would be to use a `switch`

```
def grade = { score ->
    switch( score ) {
        case 10..9: return 'love'
        case  8..6: return 'like'
        case  5..2: return 'meh'
        case  1..0: return 'hate'
        default   : return 'ERR'
    }
}

scores.collectEntries { k, v -> [ k, grade( v ) ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def scores = ["vanilla":10, "chocolate":9, "papaya": 0]

def preference = scores.collectEntries {key, value -> ["$key":(value > 5 ? "like" : "hate")]}
```

Then the result would be

```
[vanilla:like, chocolate:like, papaya:hate]
```

**EDIT**: If you want a map, then you should use collectEntries like tim_yates said.